# what view d3.js is using for the 3D visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to plot my visualization of data in a 3D view just like done in this example ([d3 3D plugin example](https://bl.ocks.org/niekes/ff4d3c8497d8436d4d8fdb9f0121d12d)) but I am not getting it that what actually they are using for the 3D visualization.

I am actually looking for the d3 3D view or the container that should be used to achieve 3D of my graph.

As an example, I wanted to have 3D view of my bar chart given below.

```
<div class="chart"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

var data = [47, 8, 155, 16, 273, 442];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

How this can be as similar to the example given above.

**NOTE:** I don't wanna use any plugin, I want to use pure d3.js.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1):

I created the plugin you have linked.

I use a [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). If you want to achieve the same result you have to take care about sorting, rotating and projecting the data all by yourself. If you want to know more, I  highly recommend reading the [docs](https://github.com/Niekes/d3-3d).

Comment: Is it compatible with d3 v6? because I am unable to create bar chart using your plugin with v6